# how to display SQLite  DataBase table?

Tags: android, sqlite

in my app i am using the database for displaying some user information, i created data base by using the SQLite DataBase Browser, and placed that database in the assets folder, this is the coding for that, i want to display this table.

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{   
private Context mycontext;
private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.slate.game/databases/";    
private static String DB_NAME = "slider.db";//the extension may be .sqlite or .db
public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;    
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) throws IOException  {
    super(context,DB_NAME,null,1);
    this.mycontext=context;
    boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
    if(dbexist)  {
        System.out.println("Database exists");
        opendatabase(); 
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
        createdatabase();
    }
    }
    public void createdatabase() throws IOException{
     boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
     if(dbexist)   {
        System.out.println(" Database exists.");
    }
    else{ this.getReadableDatabase();
    try{
        copydatabase();
    }
    catch(IOException e)  {
        throw new Error("Error copying database");
      }
     }
    }   
private boolean checkdatabase() {    
    boolean checkdb = false;
    try  {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        File dbfile = new File(myPath);
        checkdb = dbfile.exists();
    }
    catch(SQLiteException e)   {
        System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
    }
    return checkdb;
}   
private void copydatabase() throws IOException {
    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    System.out.println("outfilename"+outfilename);
    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/com.slate.game/databases/slider.db");
    // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0)   {
        myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
    }
    //Close the streams
    myoutput.flush();
    myoutput.close();
    myinput.close();
}
public void opendatabase() throws SQLException  {
    //Open the database
    String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}
public synchronized void close()  {
    if(myDataBase != null){
        myDataBase.close();
    }
    super.close();
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0)  {         
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {       
}
```

please help me how to display this table(database)..

Comment: i want how to use this class to display data in activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally i got answer from this BOOK

```
Beginning.Android.Application.Development.
```

using the SQLite i prepared database from that i will get row's and display using the TableLayout with TextView..

this is the database adapter class

```
public class DBAdapter3x3  {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_MOVES = "moves";
public static final String KEY_TIME = "time";
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SliderDB3x3.db";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "topscore3x3"; 
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table topscore3x3 " +
                                        "(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                                        + "name text not null, moves integer not null," 
                                        + "time text not null);";

private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter3x3(Context ctx)    {
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper    {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context)     {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)   {
        try  {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)   {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

//---opens the database---
public DBAdapter3x3 open() throws SQLException      {

    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//---closes the database---
public void close()   {
    DBHelper.close();
}

//---insert a contact into the database---
public long insertContact(String name, int moves,String time)   {

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_MOVES, moves);
    initialValues.put(KEY_TIME, time);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

//---deletes a particular contact---
public boolean deleteContact(long rowId)    {

    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

//---retrieves all the contacts---
public Cursor getAllContacts()  {

    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
            KEY_MOVES, KEY_TIME}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

//---retrieves a particular contact---
public Cursor getContact(long rowId) throws SQLException    {

    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, 
                     KEY_MOVES, KEY_TIME}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

//---updates a contact---
public boolean updateContact(long rowId, String name, int moves, String time)   {

    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    args.put(KEY_MOVES, moves);
    args.put(KEY_TIME, time);       
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
//public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {


public Cursor SortAllRows() {
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, 
             KEY_MOVES,KEY_TIME}, null, null, null, null, KEY_MOVES + " ASC");
}
}
```

i used database in this activity

```
public class TopScore3x3 extends Activity  {

private DBAdapter3x3 db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.db3x3);      

    db = new DBAdapter3x3(this);        
    getall();    
    delete();

private void delete()  {

    db.open();       
    Cursor c = db.SortAllRows();
    int i=1;
    if (c.moveToFirst())   {        
        do {            
            if(i>10) { db.deleteContact(i); } 
            i++;
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
}   

private void getall()  {
    //---get all contacts---
    db.open();
    //db.fetchAllNotes();
    Cursor c = db.SortAllRows();
    int i=1;
    if (c.moveToFirst())   {        
        do {
            DisplayContact(c,i++);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
} 

public void DisplayContact(Cursor c,int row )   {            

     String name11 = c.getString(1) + c.getString(2) + c.getString(3);           
     tv1.setText(name11 );

  }
 }
```

Comment: Would you please see my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265852/sqlite-database-doest-update-listview-item-and-inserts-new-instead

Answer (score 1):

use following function to retrieve data from database

```
/**
 * This function used to select the records from DB.
 * @param tableName
 * @param tableColumns
 * @param whereClase
 * @param whereArgs
 * @param groupBy
 * @param having
 * @param orderBy
 * @return A Cursor object, which is positioned before the first entry.
 */
public Cursor selectRecordsFromDB(String tableName, String[] tableColumns,String whereClase, String whereArgs[], String groupBy,String having, String orderBy) 
{
    return myDataBase.query(tableName, tableColumns, whereClase, whereArgs,groupBy, having, orderBy);
}

/**
 * select records from db and return in list
 * @param tableName
 * @param tableColumns
 * @param whereClase
 * @param whereArgs
 * @param groupBy
 * @param having
 * @param orderBy
 * @return ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>
 */
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> selectRecordsFromDBList(String tableName, String[] tableColumns,String whereClase, String whereArgs[], String groupBy,String having, String orderBy)
{       

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> retList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
      ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
      Cursor cursor = myDataBase.query(tableName, tableColumns, whereClase, whereArgs,
                groupBy, having, orderBy);        
      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
      {
         do 
            {
             list = new ArrayList<String>();
             for(int i=0; i<cursor.getColumnCount(); i++)
             {                   
               list.add( cursor.getString(i) );
             }   
             retList.add(list);
         } while (cursor.moveToNext());
      }
      if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
         cursor.close();
      }
      return retList;

}
```

Comment: @polam   follow the steps below:  1)find xml layout of listview 2)open database with database name,table name 3)  public ArrayList<UserBO> getUsers()
    {     

  DBAdapter dbAdapter=DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(this);
  try {
   dbAdapter.createDataBase();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   Log.i("*** select ",e.getMessage());
  }
     dbAdapter.openDataBase();  
  String query="SELECT * FROM profiledatabase";
  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stringList = dbAdapter.selectRecordsFromDBList(query, null);
  dbAdapter.close();
3)then with the help og arrayadapter and listadapter get position n show

Comment: i am getting error here public ArrayList<UserBO> getUsers() {  i am new to this please help me..

Comment: use curser to traverse through data retrieved from select query

Comment: LAS_VEGAS also shared same link that is not suitable.

Comment: my req. is after completion of the game, popup one window through that i will get string i want store that string in the data base programatically, with UI. in the above link not like that.

Comment: so u want to insert data in database

Comment: to insert data in DB use insert(tableName, nullColumnHack, initialValues) function of SQLiteDatabase

Comment: u want to display data from database then use query(tableName, tableColumns, whereClase, whereArgs,groupBy, having, orderBy) funtion of SQLiteDatabse which returns Curser then traverse to that curser and get each value from DB

Comment: I copy and pasted this code into an SQLiteOpenHelper, thanks swan!

Answer (score 1):

Check this: http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors/2/

Use `Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null)` to get results, iterating is explained there.

Comment: you didn't specify which data and what exactly you want to siply!@ you ask the writers here which to use ? textview or list view ? you should answer this question! you have data and should display it you can get currsor and what to do with it is up to you and you requirement which we don't know...
besides that why r you extending SQLiteOpenHelper ? you are not using it, once u'll try to get readable or writable DB form it it will create a new one or will be confused with the one exists.

Comment: already i explained clearly, i created database using SQliteDataBase i want to how display that database in activity.