# SQLite Database does't update listview item and inserts new instead

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

When item of `listview` is clicked, it gets opened in another activity which has `edittext`. After editing an item, when I save it, item does not get updated in the listview but it inserts a new entry in listview.

**How can I update existing item without inserting new?**

Here is my code

Activity: `TRList.class`

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items = new ArrayList<>();
List<TRListFormat> list = trDb.getAllReminders();

for (TRListFormat val : list) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("title",val.getTitle());
    map.put("description", val.getDes());
    map.put("date", val.getDate());
    map.put("time", val.getTime());

    items.add(map);
}

adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, items, R.layout.tr_list_format,
            new String[] { "title", "description", "date", "time" },
            new int[] {R.id.tbr_title, R.id.tbr_des, R.id.tbr_date, R.id.tbr_time });

lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.tbr_list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(TRList.this, TRTimeReminder.class);
            intent.putExtra("remId", (int)id);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
});
```

When `listView` item is clicked, it opens another activity

`TRTimeReminder.class` I have set **save button** in `menu`

```
case R.id.menu_tbr_done:
            String title = edTitle.getText().toString();
            String des = edDes.getText().toString();
            String time = timeView.getText().toString();
            String date = dateView.getText().toString();

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(extras != null) {
                int value = extras.getInt("remId");
                if (value > 0) {
                    trDb.updateReminder(new TRListFormat(value, title, des, date, time));
                }
            }
            else{
                trDb.addReminder(new TRListFormat(title, des, date, time));
            }

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TRList.class);
            startActivity(i);

            edTitle.getText().clear();
            edDes.getText().clear();
            dateView.setText(currDate);
            timeView.setText(currTime);

            return true;
```

`TRDBHelper.class`

```
//Add new reminder
void addReminder(TRListFormat format){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_TITLE, format.getTitle());
    values.put(COLUMN_DES, format.getDes());
    values.put(COLUMN_DATE, format.getDate());
    values.put(COLUMN_TIME, format.getTime());

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}

//Update single reminder
public void updateReminder(TRListFormat format){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    int id = format.getId();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_ID, format.getId());
    values.put(COLUMN_TITLE, format.getTitle());
    values.put(COLUMN_DES, format.getDes());
    values.put(COLUMN_DATE, format.getDate());
    values.put(COLUMN_TIME, format.getTime());

    db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, COLUMN_ID+ " = " +id, null);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Please post the code where you are creating your adapter.

Comment: I'm not sure about SQLite, but I observed this behavior using MS SQL Server for an application I wrote a while back. The call to Update inserted a row if there was no row to be updated.

Comment: Are you sure that your `updateReminder` method is called, and not `addReminder`?

Comment: @Marcus if you see the code of my **save button**, I have set `updateReminder` only when the id is >0, otherwise it will insert a new reminder. See the if..else.. in my code. I guess I'm doing something wrong there.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Thanks but I guess it has nothing to do with adapter. It inserts an item and retrieves too so there is no mistake my adapter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978136/sqlite-db-update,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798473/sqlite-in-android-how-to-update-a-specific-row

Comment: Sorry but i don't think `db.update` notifies your adapter, if i'm not wrong to do that you need to use a `ContentResolver`

Answer (score 1):

I think there's problem with your adapter. There are 2 possible issues.

1. Data of adapter are not updated. You're saying opposite, new value is added to ListView. Are you really sure?
2. You haven't called your adapter's method [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) after you've changed values.

Comment: could you tell me how to update adapter? And yes it does make a new entry in listview.

Comment: I have added adapter code at the beginning of `TRList.class` check my question.

Comment: Solved it! I needed to make a little change in intent of `TRList.class` I just changed `intent.putExtra("remId", (int)id);` with `int remId = (int)id + 1; Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle(); dataBundle.putInt("remId", remId); intent.putExtras(dataBundle);`