# Cannot use notifyDataSetChanged to update adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I cannot update my `ListView` after deleting an item. Listview item gets deleted from database but I cannot update my adapter and it keeps showing deleted item in listView.

if I put `adapter.notiftDataSetChanged();` it turns into **red** colored code strangely! And shows that `cannot resolve the method notifyDataSetChanged().`

Here is my code.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items = new ArrayList<>();
List<TRListFormat> list = trDb.getAllReminders();

for (TRListFormat val : list) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("title",val.getTitle());
    map.put("description", val.getDes());
    map.put("date", val.getDate());
    map.put("time", val.getTime());

    items.add(map);
}

adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, items, R.layout.tr_list_format,
          new String[] { "title", "description", "date", "time" },
          new int[] {R.id.tbr_title, R.id.tbr_des, R.id.tbr_date, R.id.tbr_time });

lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.tbr_list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

my `setOnItemClickListener`, it displays `AlertDialog` with 3 buttons as the listview item is clicked.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, final long id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TRList.this);
            builder.setTitle("Select the Action");
            builder.setMessage("Do anything");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Edit",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            int remId = (int)id;
                            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
                            dataBundle.putInt("remId", remId);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TRTimeReminder.class);
                            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
            builder.setNeutralButton("Deactivate",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        }
                    });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Delete",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            int remId = (int)id + 1;
                            TRListFormat format = trDb.getReminder(remId);
                            String title = format.getTitle();
                            String des = format.getDes();
                            String date = format.getDate();
                            String time = format.getTime();
                            trDb.deleteReminder(new TRListFormat(remId, title, des, date, time));

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reminder: "+title+"deleted",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  //this line shows an error I have written above
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK error is `cannot resolve method 'notifyDataSetChanged()'`

Comment: @Rohit5k2 I already have defined adapter at class level (before `onCreate()` method).

Comment: Yeah got it from error statement in the comment. I saw error in the post `cannot resolve the symbol` so I thought that could be the issue.

Comment: Try `adapterView.getAdapter()`

Comment: @Rohit5k2 oh sorry, I edited error in my question

Comment: @Rohit5k2 instead of adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()??

Comment: adapterView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @Rohit5k2 tried, does't work, shows same error

Comment: @danny117 doesn't work! I tried it too, I try to solve this since 2 days, still got no solution

Comment: I get it. `notifyDataSetChanged` is not available for `SimpleAdapter`. Let me write an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1** (Preferred)

`notifyDataSetChanged` is not available for `SimpleAdapter`.
`SimpleAdapter` is meant for static data. You should use a different type of adapter, like `ArrayAdapter`. More information is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html)

**Solution 2**

Call this method instead of `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

```
public void refreshList(){
    List<TRListFormat> list = trDb.getAllReminders();
    items = new ArrayList<>();
    for (TRListFormat val : list) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("title",val.getTitle());
        map.put("description", val.getDes());
        map.put("date", val.getDate());
        map.put("time", val.getTime());

        items.add(map);
    }

    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, items, R.layout.tr_list_format,
      new String[] { "title", "description", "date", "time" },
      new int[] {R.id.tbr_title, R.id.tbr_des, R.id.tbr_date, R.id.tbr_time     });

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: I got it! I need to update it every time I make a change in listview  but declaring the method `refreshList()` as `public` gives lots of errors `cannot resolve the symbol`. and if I dont declare refreshList() as public it shows error right after `refreshList()`. error is `expected ;`

Comment: You must have put method inside another method by mistake. check it.

Comment: oh! solved it. Now it updates the list but it only deletes the item from database not from listView. deleted item is still there in listView

Comment: That was my mistake. Please see my edited code. Added `items = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: if `trDb.deleteReminder(new TRListFormat(remId, title, des, date, time));` is really deleting the reminder from database and `trDb.getAllReminders();` fetching updated reminders (after deletion) then my code would work perfectly.

Comment: could you please help me solving this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265852/sqlite-database-doest-update-listview-item-and-inserts-new-instead