# Error: Cannot Resolve method notifyDataSetChanged(); Android

Tags: android, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I am trying to implement searchbar in gridview.So for that i am trying to use notifydatasetchanged() in customfilter but it says method cannot be resolved.Here is the code.Thankyou in advance.

```
package com.example.krishna.pokemongopokemons;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by krishna on 7/15/2016.
 */
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    private Context mContext;
    CustomFilter filter;

    String[] x;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c,String[] x) {
        mContext = c;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override



    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View grid;


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ViewHolder mVHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, parent, false);
            mVHolder=new ViewHolder();
            mVHolder.mImageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            //mVHolder.mTextView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            convertView.setTag(mVHolder);

            /*grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);*/
            //imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(3,3));
            //imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            //imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            //imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

        } else {
            mVHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

            //grid = (View) convertView;
        }
        //TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        mVHolder.mImageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        mVHolder.mTextView.setText(web[position]);
        textView.setText(web[position]);

        return convertView;}




    // references to our images

    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {..
    ..};
    //references to textview
    String[] web = {
            ......
    } ;

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if(filter==null){
            filter=new CustomFilter();


        }


            return filter;
    }

}
class CustomFilter extends Filter{
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
        FilterResults results=new FilterResults();
        arrays a=new arrays();
        int[] array_list=new int[150];

        if(charSequence!=null & charSequence.length()>0){
            charSequence=charSequence.toString().toUpperCase();



            for(int i=0;i<a.web.length;i++){
                if(a.web[i].toUpperCase().contains(charSequence)){
                    for(int j=0;j<array_list.length;j++){
                        if(array_list[j]==0){
                            array_list[j]=i;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            results.count=array_list.length;
            results.values=array_list;


        }
        else
        {
            results.count=a.web.length;
            results.values=a.web;
        }
        return results;

    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        int[] x= (int[]) filterResults.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();












    }


}
class ViewHolder {
    ImageView mImageView;


}
```

cant use notifydatasetchanged() in customfilter class.

```
class CustomFilter extends Filter{
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
        FilterResults results=new FilterResults();
        arrays a=new arrays();
        int[] array_list=new int[150];

        if(charSequence!=null & charSequence.length()>0){
            charSequence=charSequence.toString().toUpperCase();



            for(int i=0;i<a.web.length;i++){
                if(a.web[i].toUpperCase().contains(charSequence)){
                    for(int j=0;j<array_list.length;j++){
                        if(array_list[j]==0){
                            array_list[j]=i;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            results.count=array_list.length;
            results.values=array_list;


        }
        else
        {
            results.count=a.web.length;
            results.values=a.web;
        }
        return results;

    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        int[] x= (int[]) filterResults.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();    

    }


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot use notifyDataSetChanged to update adapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326942/cannot-use-notifydatasetchanged-to-update-adapter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make constructor to your CustomFilter class and pass the adapter there :

```
ImageAdapter myImageAdapter;
public CustomFilter(ImageAdapter imageAdapter) {
this.myImageAdapter = imageAdapter;
}
```

And then in your publishResults method :

```
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
    int[] x= (int[]) filterResults.values;
    myImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    

}
```